# Locations uploaded to Places not appearing in Query

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Places API to store points at Google site. In short, i developed a simple set of Java Classes that would make use of JSON and my **Google API Key** to post it. I recvd success message with the id,reference and status det. Let me make it clear that I am not an Enterprise customer and I am not paying any money to Google for maintaining the points.

Next, I made a simple HTML page(not JSP) built using Google Maps and Places Javascript API  wherein i have text boxes enabled with Places AutoComplete facility. I am making use of the **Google API Key** in the URL to invoke the maps. The HTML page works fine. But when i search for the places which i entered in first step, i am unable to retrieve them.

I am aware that these points pass through a moderation process before it is made available to others. However Google Documentation says that it would available to the application which uploaded it.

a) How does Google identify which application contributed the point? I guess it should be the encrypted Application Key which is used at the time of placing an Add Place request. However there is no clear guidance on this.

b) Second, How can i retrieve the points that i submitted in the first step?

Regards

Govindarajan

Comment: Govindarajan - did you ever get an answer from Google on this?

Comment: Mike, apologies as i didnt check this thread for a while. From what i understand, it appears to be a short coming with Google Places API. Refer to the post by Chris Green on this page on 5 Oct 12. This needs to be submitted to Google as a request for enhancement.- Govindarajan

Answer (score 0):

Only [Place Report Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#PlaceReportRequests) submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places.

If you wish to add a new place that can be accessed outside of your application you can follow the Google Maps help instructions to [Add a new place](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144367&topic=1687361&ctx=topic).

If you are a business owner, you can add and verify your business on Google Maps using [Google Places for Business](http://www.google.com/placesforbusiness).

Another alternative to add places to Google Maps is to submit an edit through [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) by following the [instructions](http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1096044&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1wf9zf83h3bs7&cbrank=2) from Google Map Maker Help.

Your added place will appear in Google Maps after it has been reviewed and accepted.

Comment: Thanks!! I am making use of the SAME key to post POINTS as well as to retrieve it. I have about 16000 points. As i explained i am using plain java classes that make use of HTTP POST to send the data with the Google API key. I make USE OF THE SAME KEY in a HTML based application to access the points and i have been unsuccessful in that. I repeat i want to automate the process of loading using HTTP POST and access it from another application. BOTH APPS MAKE USE OF THE SAME GOOGLE API KEY. My understanding is Google uses the API key to identify the app which contributed the data.

Comment: Hi Chris Thanks again. I posted the details of how i am currently approaching this as an another response to this. Can u please verify and let me know? Thanks for ur time and assistance

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks Again. Can u please verify the procedure that i had posted here and guide me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering.

I followed the following steps to obtain the API

a) Logged into APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console
b) Clicked the Services link from the left-hand menu.
c) ACTIVATED the Google **Maps API v3 service**, Places API, Google Coordinate, Static Map API(**ALL AT THE SAME TIME**) but ignored Google **Maps API v2** service 
d) Clicked the API Access link from the left-hand menu. Made use of the API key from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section!

[My Google API console after removing sensitive information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgfkC.png)

My understanding was that the API key generated after enabling Google Places and Google Maps API v3 would be common to both. It is this API which i used in Map JavaScript as well as in the Java classes for HTTP post of data.

[image]

When i posted the data using the API Key for browser Apps it posted the data and i got the status as OK. Going by your logic how did Google Places accept the Key for Browser Apps?

Comment: You are correct my previous response did not take this into account. This being the case; places, events and check-ins added with the web service should all be accessible via the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 if you provide the same API Key. This is currently not available, please add this as a [Places API Feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request)!